# Почему неправильно срабатывает CSS селектор?

Tags: css

Привет всем, пишу вот такой CSS:

```
footer:not(.copyright){
    font-size: 540% !important;
}
.copyright{
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

А увеличивается почему-то только текст с классом copyright. Почему так происходит?

[Ссылка](http://dental2.brandivo.com/)

Comment: Я у вас в footer, кроме .copyright, ничего и не вижу.

Comment: @Дмитрий Клименко А 4 колонки не видите с виджетами?

Comment: @MasterAlex спасибо, оформите комментарий как ответ, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для нахождения всех элементов, кроме определённого, селектор нужно написать так:

```
footer *:not(.copyright){
    font-size: 540% !important;
}
```

Comment: @eprivalov1, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Пример то рабочий, но так писать... Лучше уж конкретно для footer и footer .copyright стили прописать

Comment: @inferusvv, вопрос ведь был не в том, как лучше сделать футер, а в том, почему не работает селектор, а когда сталкиваешься с CMS, ещё и не такие костыли писать приходится  :)